# Calculating remainder in big query with floating data points

Tags: google-bigquery, hiveql

Hive query language has a PMOD function which can be used to calculate the remainder. This function works perfectly fine with integers and double. For example, calculate the remainder when 4.7 is divided by 2.

**SELECT PMOD(4.7,2);**

The answer to this query in hive query language is 0.7

Google big query has MOD function to calculate the remainder. But this function only works with integers.

**SELECT MOD(4.7,2);** does not work in google big query.

It is possible to cast 4.7 as INT64 in big query. Then the MOD function will work but the answer will be 1 and not 0.7

Any help to calculate the remainder with floating data points in google big query will be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating remainder of a floating point value is an interesting concept, personally I have never heard about it so far.
According to your description it is basically all about finding remainder of an integer part and adding up a fractional part to the result?
If so, it could probably be imitated by using the following expression (in your example): `MOD(FLOOR(4.7),2) + 4.7 - FLOOR(4.7)` considering that the integer part is `FLOOR(4.7)` and the fractional part is thus `4.7 - FLOOR(4.7)`

UPD. This one assumed the non-negative floating point values, in case of negative values the fractional part is obviously `value - CEIL(value)`. Using `value - TRUNC(value)` would generalize finding fractional part for both cases, but I am not pretty sure about the outcome of `MOD()` on negative values so I would leave it to you

Comment: Thanks Mangusta. I made the minor modification to your code and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks for pointing to logic. I have no negatives at the moment.   MOD(CAST(FLOOR(4.7) AS INT64),2) + 4.7 - FLOOR(4.7)

Comment: @user3601140 glad it helped, I suspect that hive's `pmod` was actually doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, MOD is defined on NUMERIC datatypes and appears to work just fine with floats. It just errors out if you pass it arguments of type FLOAT64. So what you can do is

```
SELECT MOD(CAST(4.7 AS NUMERIC), CAST(2 AS NUMERIC))
```

As opposed to mangusta's answer above, this also works if your second argument is also a float. E.g.

```
SELECT MOD(CAST(2.5 AS NUMERIC), CAST(0.4 AS NUMERIC))
```

This will return 0.1, as that is the remainder of 2.5 - 6*0.4.

The other, obvious solution, is if you know you have a fixed number of decimals (lets call this N), you can just multiply both sides by 10^N. So in the case of 2 decimals you can just multiply both sides by 100, cast to ints and be sure your MOD operation is working correctly. If you have an arbitrary number of decimals, then I guess just trust BQ to do the upcasting and then MOD correctly (and I am fairly confident it does indeed work correctly).